# Overriding Django auto_now in datefiled

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to pass a date to datafield that overrides auto_now?  I want to only use auto_now if a date is not passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs:

> Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default
>   value that you can override.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield

So just don't use auto_now, use default, for example:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class YourModel(models.Model):
    date_approved = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```