# Django: Having error when add auto_now in DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do django api.

In models.py

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(),null=True,blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,editable=False)
```

I got error if I add in `auto_now =True`,`editable=False`. Here is my error message.

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'updated_at' cannot be specified for Receipt model form as it is a non-editable field
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 256, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/uadmin/django/project/project/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from apps import views
  File "/home/uadmin/django/project/apps/views.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .forms import ReceiptForm
  File "/home/uadmin/django/project/apps/forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    class ReceiptForm(ModelForm):
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 266, in __new__
    apply_limit_choices_to=False,
  File "/home/uadmin/django/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 159, in fields_for_model
    f.name, model.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'updated_at' cannot be specified for Receipt model form as it is a non-editable field
```

What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: please send your whole model

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question. It will show where the error is coming from.

Comment: Just in case, as you've added model fields, you're getting error for `Receipt` model, not `Book`. Either you just missing it you you're having non-described relations

Comment: The traceback is telling you that the error is occurring in `ReceiptForm`, so you should include that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error as you could see in traceback is in you form `ReceiptForm`. `DateTimeField` with `auto_now` are `editable=False` and `blank=True` automatically, therefore could not be included in a form unless it's readonly. You could remove `auto_now` and use a custom save method to set `updated_at`.

See these questions for more info:

- [Django auto_now and auto_now_add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737017/django-auto-now-and-auto-now-add)
- [Overriding Django auto_now in datefiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191848/overriding-django-auto-now-in-datefiled)
- [Can't display DateField on form with auto_now = True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033422/cant-display-datefield-on-form-with-auto-now-true)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve?

[`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) is to set field value for *every save*. You can't override this.

[`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) is to make this once object is *created*.

[`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#default) is to have default value to use, when you don't provide anything.

My guess is that you simply need `default`. If not, please describe what you're solving

Comment: I want to get the last modified date time after the update operation is done. I got error too after i add in the default value.

Comment: This looks like you're using model out of sync with your code. Please edit your question with complete code to reproduce this issue